# Is there a way to do Ms Graph API authentication directly via API, without asking user to authenticate?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently trying to auto update my user's Outlook Calendar from existing system via Ms Graph API. So far I am able to do it using RefreshToken & AccessToken.
However I understand from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/340205/for-how-long-i-can-keep-using-the-refresh-token.html
that RefreshToken only last for 14 days.
If I use a refresh token within those 14 days, I will receive a new one with a new validity window shifted forward of another 14 days. I can repeat this method for up to 90 days of total validity, then my users will have to reauthenticate.

Is there a way or API to directly authenticate? so that my users dont have to re-login & re-authenticate every 90 days?

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service the heading is _"Get access without a user"_ and describes how to set-up OIDC `client_credentials` grant for your application

Comment: Duplicate question- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/930208/index.html